# Does the crypt() function in PHP return the salt if you let crypt() generate the salt?

Tags: php

I'm wondering wether or not the crypt() function returns the salt if you don't insert your own salt.

**E.G:**

```
<?php
  $password = $_POST['input'];
  $encpw = crypt($password /* no salt */);
  print $encpw;
?>
```

I'm aware this outputs the encrypted password with the random salt, but is there any way to output the randomly generated salt at all?

Comment: Reading the php.net/manual beforehand can be of great benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Right out of the [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) (emphasis mine):

> Parameters:
>
> ***str***
> The string to be hashed.
>
> ***salt***
> An optional salt string to base the hashing on. If not provided, the behaviour is defined by the algorithm implementation and **can lead to unexpected results**.

Comment: In the 1st example, it shows that you can pass the return value of `crypt` as the salt to verify passwords, but it's not recommended.

Comment: @Rocket yea... I don't like it....